# new to android - need to access bitmap object from another class

Tags: java, android

class1 has this method:

```
private Bitmap scaleImage() { 
Bitmap nad =    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

return nad;
}
```

I need to use this nad object in class2...I tried to look through some java documentation on access class properties,but nothing worked..

Answer (score 1):

You have declared you method as `private`. That prevents other classes from invoking it. You usually use the `private` modifier to guarantee encapsulation, but for your case you should use:

- `public`, meaning that any other class can invoke `scaleImage()`, or,
- `protected` to restrict it to the classes inheriting from `class1` and the classes in its same package, or,
- Use no modifier at all, which will allow access to the classes in the same package (This is the default behavior, also known as *package-private*).

For further details on access modifiers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my answer to make that clear. Nevertheless, all modifiers except private allow access to the same package. The particular purpose of protected is accessing from subclasses.

Comment: Yea, it looks much better with the edit. Less confusing that way.